# How to use a Regular Expression to find ThreadStarts with unmatched functions?

Tags: regex, search, lua, notepad++

I'm working with Notepad++ and want to use the Search in Files + regular Expressions to find in some Lua-files a error I can not get otherwise.

In my files I have functions like this:

```
function NameOfFunction()
--ToDoOrNotToDodo
end
```

and I have Thread Starting functioncalls like this:

```
StartThread(NameOfFunction, value,value..)
```

Now if the function name is misspelled, or the function otherwise throws a error, I only get the message that some nil-value was used to attempt to start a thread. No linenumbers, no scriptfile. Thus, Regex to the rescue.

Now my idea of a Regular Expression was this

```
  \s*StartThread\(\s* [CaptureTheNameAndSave],
```

and make this a match if and only if there is no corresponding

```
  \s*function\s*[CaptureTheNameAndSave]\s*(
```

found.

Comment: You can extend your `_G` to alert you when an non-existing global is requested. `setmetatable(_G,{__index=function(_,key) print("Undefined global "..key.." requested) end})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of making a complicated (or impossible) regex, why don't you solve the issue directly?

```
local oldStartThread = StartThread
function StartThread(func, ...)
    assert(func)
    return oldStartThread(func, ...)
end
```

This will replace the StartThread function with a wrapper that immediately checks if there is a function, and error if its nil, thus providing you a good traceback.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a more robust and easier solution than requested. But I wouldn't wrap the StartThread since other components of Notepad++ might use it and rely on its error-free behavior.

Comment: @Schollii I agree that this should only be done during debugging, but he says its erroring anyway, just probably later on in the program execution. If NP++ passed nil as the function, it should cause an error as well.

Answer (score 0):

As @ColonelThirtyTwo points out, why regex? Create a function that does all the checks you want and traps errors in thread:

```
function safeStartThread(func, arg1, arg2)
    -- check func isn't nil
    if func == nil then
        error('thread func cannot be nil')
        return
    end

    -- create wrapper to trap exceptions in func: 
    function trapper()
        local stat, errMsg = pcall(func, arg1, arg2)
        if stat then -- handle error
             print(errMsg) -- or whatever handling
        end
    end

    -- start thread:
    StartThread(trapper)
end
```

You could use xpcall instead of pcall if you want to get line number etc of where error occured.